# Is there a way to map fields to an existing (non VFP) PDF document?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

I have a requirement to update an existing (non-VFP) PDF with data from our opportunities.

We have a PDF with blank spaces like these:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this requirement via apex/vfp or lwc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try modifying PDF in JS via LWC via a library such as [PDF-LIB](https://pdf-lib.js.org/).

Answer (score 2):

In Apex, it would be very difficult. Consider starting from an HTML template, you can then use Blob.toPdf to render the final output. In LWC, you can use a PDF library to manipulate the PDF, but it might still be easier to start from HTML, since most libraries I've seen are more focused on converting HTML to PDF, rather than directly manipulating a PDF.